# Version to Version Upgrades and bugs -- DNS errors

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, 10.10, upgrade, dns

I've been using Ubuntu (64-bit) for the past three versions (10.10, 11.04, now 11.10). For the most part, things are fine. I have issues with the 64-bit version, but who doesn't.

My question is whether doing the upgrades for that many versions contributes to the bugs that I see.

I went from 10.10 to 11.04 by using the built-in upgrade process. From there, I went to 11.10 with the same process.

I seem to get various DNS errors (such as trying to go to facebook sends me to a server that has nothing to do with facebook.) This doesn't seem to happen on my Windows (work) or MacBook (notebook) computers.

I've been thinking of doing a clean install with the hopes that it will solve some of the issues I see. But, I really have no basis to believe this will actually help.

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
domain hsd1.il.comcast.net.
search hsd1.il.comcast.net.
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 68.87.72.134
nameserver 68.87.77.134
```

Comment: That doesn't sound like a problem that could be caused by version-to-version upgrades.  If you're having DNS issues, it would be helpful if you could update your question to include the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`, and say whether your web browser is configured to use a proxy.

Comment: Posted. The actual issue has been persisting for a number of versions. I don't know if it's issues between Linux and my router or just my ISP (which is Comcast -- a cable provider in the chicagoland area)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As queueoverflow stated, there is a service comcast uses which sends you to ad pages on DNS failures.

I got around this by *not* using Comcast DNS.  In NetworkManager, I configured my ethernet and wifi interfaces to have `8.8.8.8` and `4.2.2.4` as my DNS servers.

In the `resolv.conf`, you'd simply have

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.2.2.4
```

Since, though, your resolv.conf is generated by network manager you'll have to edit whatever interface you are using, go to the IPv4 tab, set it to "IPv4 addresses only", and under "DNS Servers" enter `8.8.8.8,4.2.2.4`.

THis will also nix the search domain and what not, but will enforce those DNS servers only.

Comment: Thanks. I've attempted to manipulate this at my router's configurations since I'd prefer to avoid going through comcast all together....

Answer (score 2):

Comcast has a "service" which redirects you do a search page if the DNS request would fail otherwise. That way, they can show you ads and make profit. The huge downside is that every DNS request succeeds from your computer's point of view. Therefore, there is no clear fail on a DNS, which leads to problems.